# How to use rhs of a given list in a code?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, replacement, rule

I have the following Mathematica code:

```
lagrangian = Sum[Derivative[1][c[n]][t]^2 - c[n][t]^2*\[Omega]sq[n], {n, {0, 1}}] + K1*c[0][t]^3 + K2*c[0][t]*c[1][t]^2 + K3*c[0][t]*Derivative[1][c[0]][t]^2 + 
    K4*c[0][t]*Derivative[1][c[1]][t]^2 + K5*Derivative[1][c[0]][t]*c[1][t]*Derivative[1][c[1]][t]; 
c[0][t_] := OverTilde[c][0][t] + \[Alpha]1*OverTilde[c][0][t]^2 + \[Alpha]2*OverTilde[c][1][t]^2; 
c[1][t_] := OverTilde[c][1][t] + \[Alpha]3*OverTilde[c][0][t]*OverTilde[c][1][t]; 
n = Expand[lagrangian]; 
vars = {OverTilde[c][0][t], OverTilde[c][1][t], Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][0]][t], Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][1]][t]}; 
lagrangianmod = Normal[Series[n /. Thread[vars -> m*vars], {m, 0, 3}]] /. m -> 1
eulerLagrange[lagrangianmod_, vars_, dvars_] := Thread[Table[D[D[lagrangianmod, dvar], t], {dvar, dvars}] - Table[D[lagrangianmod, var], {var, vars}] == 
     ConstantArray[0, Length[vars]]]; 
equationsOfMotion = eulerLagrange[lagrangianmod, {OverTilde[c][0][t], OverTilde[c][1][t]}, {Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][0]][t], Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][1]][t]}]
eom = Simplify[SolveValues[equationsOfMotion, {Derivative[2][OverTilde[c][0]][t], Derivative[2][OverTilde[c][1]][t]}][[1]] /. {OverTilde[c][0] -> c0, OverTilde[c][1] -> c1}]
ClearAll[firstOrderize]; 
Options[firstOrderize] = {"NewSymbolGenerator" -> (Unique["y"] & )}; 
firstOrderize[sys_, vars_, t_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{fop, newsym, toNewVar}, newsym = OptionValue["NewSymbolGenerator"]; 
    fop = Internal`ProcessEquations`FirstOrderize[sys, {t}, 1, vars]; If[newsym === Automatic, Flatten[fop[[1 ;; 2]]], 
     toNewVar = With[{newvars = MapIndexed[newsym, fop[[3]], {2}]}, Internal`ProcessEquations`FirstOrderReplace[#1, {t}, 1, vars, newvars] & ]; 
      Flatten[{toNewVar[fop[[1]] /. Last[fop]], Activate[toNewVar[Inactivate[Evaluate[fop[[2]]], Derivative]] /. toNewVar[fop[[4]]]]}]]]
eqs = firstOrderize[{Derivative[2][c0][t] == eom[[1]], Derivative[2][c1][t] == eom[[2]]}, {c0, c1}, t, 
   "NewSymbolGenerator" -> (Symbol[StringJoin[{"a", "b"}[[First[#2]]], ToString[Last[#2]]]] & )]
```

I want to make a new list from the above code in such a way that:

```
f = {rhs of eqs[[3]], rhs of eqs[[1]], rhs of eqs[[4]], rhs of eqs[[2]]}
```

How to go about doing this without manually copying the result?

Comment: Try `{eqs[[3, 2]], eqs[[1, 2]], eqs[[4, 2]], eqs[[2, 2]]}`

Comment: @DanielHuber thanks a lot!

Comment: In the future consider giving a small example of what the problem is. Seeing a chunk of code is scary and might lead members to skip the question  while the actual problem is a rather simple question with lists. You could have even just given the four first elements of the list  as an example and omitted the code

Comment: @userrandrand I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the rearrangement is something you want to be able to specify, then Permute might come in handy:

```
f = Permute[eqs, {2, 4, 1, 3}][[All, 2]]
```

The list `{2,4,1,3}` is the permutation. Then we can use normal Part syntax, the `[[All,2]]` bit, to extract the second element of every member of the resulting list.

It turns out that you can also just use a special form of Part:

```
f = eqs[[{3, 1, 4, 2}, 2]]
```

In this case, we use the list `{3,1,4,2}` because Part expects a list of indices.